# Matrix ODE- Solution curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=Ax$, with $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\-3 & -4\end{pmatrix}$

I solved the eigenvectors and eigenvalues and for the solution I got

$x(t)=c_1e^{-t}\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\\ -1 \\\end{array}\right)-c_2e^{-3t}\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\\ -3 \\\end{array}\right)$

Now the point where I am stuck is that **the solution curves which are equivalent to the eigenspace of the matrix** need to be drawn/plotted.

The eigenspace of A is equal to $u\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\\ -3 \\\end{array}\right) + v\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\\ -1 \\\end{array}\right) $

I try to play around with desmos here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eijhparfmd
but do not know what to do, should I just draw a vector with direction "$\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\\ -3 \\\end{array}\right)$" and $\left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\\ -1 \\\end{array}\right)$ resp.?

Comment: [Try this.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mnvyu0ax3k)

Comment: @K.defaoite: thank you very much